# Fullscreen landing page that automatically jumps to a normal scrolling webpage when scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullscreen

I am trying to make a landing page / "cover screen" for projects in my portfolio that does not allow scrolling, but when you scroll the mouse wheel down, it jumps you to the top of the content page (which is below) automatically, where scrolling is normal. 2 sections: the fullscreen landing page, then the text/content underneath.

Here is code I used from a video which has previous/next sections buttons, and accomplishes almost everything I want (except being able to scroll normally in the second section). The first section is the landing page that has a height of the window. The second section has a height of however long the content is (much bigger than just the window height). I am trying to make it so I can't scroll on the landing page, but as soon as the wheel is scrolled, the user is automatically brought to the top of section 2. (so the user is only able to see the landing page if it is fullscreen)

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');

let index = 0;
const animationDuration = 1000;
let lastTime = 0;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (index > 0) return;
    index++;
    sections.forEach((section, i) =>
    {
        if (i === index){
            section.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
        }
    })

    });

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (index < 1) return;
    index--;
    sections.forEach((section, i) =>
    {
        if (i === index){
            section.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
        }
    })

    });

window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    const delta = e.wheelDelta;
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    if (currentTime - lastTime < animationDuration){
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    if (delta < 0) {
        const nextBtnClick = new Event('click');
        nextBtn.dispatchEvent(nextBtnClick);
    }
    else
    {
        const prevBtnClick = new Event('click');
        prevBtn.dispatchEvent(prevBtnClick);

    }
    lastTime = currentTime;
})
```

```
body{
    margin:0px;
}

main{
    height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}

section{
    height:100vh;
    position: relative;
}

section:nth-child(1){
    height:100vh;    
    background:blue;
}

section:nth-child(2){
    background:green;
    height:2000px;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}

.text{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
}


.nav{
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}
```

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="scroll.css"/>
        

    </head>
    

  <body>
    <main>

    <div class="content">

    <section>
        <div class="text">
            <h1>section 1</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="text">
            <h1>section 2</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <button class="prev">previous</button>
        <button class="next">next</button>
    </div>

</main>
<script src="scroll.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is, if I disable overflow to disable scrolling, I can only do it for the entire webpage, and can't scroll normally in section 2. Disable overflow does not seem to have the effect I want if I apply it for either section.

If possible, I would like if scrolling to the top of the content would automatically jump the user back to the landing page which would again cover the whole screen.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I do notice that you use very few class or ID selectors to style your HTML. They are almost all [type selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors/Selectors_and_combinators#basic_selectors). This makes your CSS code very inflexible. You already need to resort to `:nth-child(1)` and `:nth-child(2)` just to select the sections. It is normal practice to use [ID selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) in this case, and give the IDs meaningful names. It also simplifies setting the height.